# webbrowser script executes without error, but nothing happens?

Tags: python, browser

Im writing a script which is supposed to open different browser with given urls.

When I run it in eclipse it runs the script without errors, but no browsers open. :/

```
import webbrowser as wb

url_mf = ['https://www.thatsite.com/','http://thatothersite.org/']
url_gc = ['https://www.thatsite.com/','http://thatothersite.org/']

chrome = wb.get('/usr/bin/google-chrome %s')
firefox = wb.get('fierfox %s')

chrome.open(url_gc[1], new=1)
firefox.open(url_mf[1], new=1)
```

I also have a script using the IEC.py module to open Internet explorer (I need to enter login info and, later, extract horribly unformatted db queries from a site - mechanize & selenium seemed a bit over the top for that?),  and that works just fine. But I'm guessing that's like comparing apples and oranges?

```
import iec
ie= iec.IEController()
ie.Navigate(url_ie[1])
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you use `open_new` instead of `open`? what happens if you run it from command line (not from eclipse)?

Comment: `fierfox %s` => `firefox %s` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed is the typo on line 5. It should be `Firefox` instead of `fierfox`. Second thing, I ran your code in SublimeText 2, I had no problems, I changed the paths because I'm on a windows machine.

The code below opened both Firefox and Chrome.

```
import webbrowser as wb

url_mf = ['https://www.thatsite.com/','http://www.google.ie/']
url_gc = ['https://www.thatsite.com/','http://www.google.ie/']

chrome = wb.get('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %s')
firefox = wb.get('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe" %s')

chrome.open(url_gc[1], new=1)
firefox.open(url_mf[1], new=1)
```

Do you really want to specify which browser the program wants to use ?, I'd suggest using

```
import webbrowser as wb

urls = ["http://www.google.ie/","http://www.gametrailers.com/"]

for url in urls:
    wb.open(url,new=2, autoraise=True)
```

This would just get your default browser and open each of the links in new tabs.

Comment: it needs to be seperate browsers and also different ones, yes. Usually I just use chrome, but some of the website i want to access only work with IE, and some others require firefox plugins.

Comment: I tried it on my windows machine as well, and it works. I dont know what magical property that path has, that the other ddnt, but its working now. Which is fine, the script will be run on windows anyways. Still a bit odd. Thank you anyways!